# Change font on styles in MS Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

When I'm working in Excel, sometimes I'll highlight a couple cells and click on the "Good" style in the Styles section:

[image: styles]
<sub>(source: [polymathprogrammer.com](http://polymathprogrammer.com/images/blog/201102/excelopenxmlbuiltinstyles.png))</sub>

My default font for all of my text is **Arial**.  When I use these styles, it switches to **Calibri**.

Is there any way to change the default font for all of these styles to **Arial**?  I can't figure this out for the life of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I started typing this up, I figured it out (mind you, this has been driving me nuts for months now).

Right click on the style and unselect the **Font** option.  This will allow you to use your default font.  <strike>It doesn't give you the option to specify your own font without creating a new custom style (which is pretty annoying)</strike> Ok, so you go to **Format** then the **Font** tab  Not exactly clear:

[image: modify style]
<sub>(source: [contextures.com](http://blog.contextures.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/headerfont02.png))</sub>

[image: unselect font]
<sub>(source: [computergaga.com](https://www.computergaga.com/excel/2007/foundation/formatting_a_worksheet/images/modify_style_format.JPG))</sub>